# Can I have my account suspended or deleted for a limited period of time?

Tags: support, accounts, account-suspension

I would like to know how one can temporary delete (or maybe suspend) his account here (7-9 months). I mean all your profiles on SE sites for a period of time and come back?

No follow on accounts. Totally anonymous for that period. I am not talking permanent. I have seen the other post about permanent deletion.

Is it currently possibly? If not can one achieve this by some hack or so? Also what happens when one returns after permanent deletion?

Comment: Did you get some moderator notification?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ notification like how? but overall no i have not,

Comment: I have edited your question to say what I think you're asking. Could you verify and confirm, or otherwise roll back?

Comment: @Bart yes that is what i am trying to say, thank you

Comment: This question has been asked before and I think the answer is "no."

Comment: Pretty much. A suspension would be a black mark on your account, so those aren't handed out without reason. And deleting accounts is permanent. There is no coming back really. If you have really strong (non public) reasons, use the "contact us" link on the page and contact the team directly.

Comment: @Pekka웃 no for all the options being asked for?

Comment: @Bart so if i should request a permanent deletion now and come back like a year later, i will come as fresh user right?

Comment: `no for all the options being asked for?` yup, unfortunately. An option to lock yourself out for a while might make sense, but it doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes. You would have to make a completely new account. And keep in mind that account deletion is not instant. You seem to have been fairly active, so if you request deletion, it will take some time to process.

Comment: An alternative might be logging out and asking a friend to change the password, and to give it to you in x months' time.

Comment: @Bart _"A suspension would be a black mark on your account,"_ I'm worrying now :(

Comment: How is this "unclear what you are asking"? If you *need* to see this closed, then go search for the right duplicate.

Comment: @Pekka웃 sadly, we can't close as duplicated to a [bookmarked chat conversation](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/i-need-a-mod-to-suspend-me)

Comment: What is the purpose? You want a forced [wikiholiday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wikibreak)?

Comment: You've got me curious ... What is the purpose of your account holiday? Guess #1: Did you accidently post some NDA material and you want the NDA to expire. If so just edit that material out and ask a Moderator to ask a DB Dev to delete the offending original post. Guess#2: Is your spouse Stackoverflow obsessed and you want them to take a forced break? Then change their password and schedule an auto-email to deliver the new password to them in 6 months.

Comment: Agreed with @markE - this sounds intensely like an XY problem.  What is the actual problem you are trying to solve by doing this?  Surely, whatever it is, this is not the best solution.

Comment: Sounds like they're battling SO addiction

Comment: 1) randomly generate a long and complex password https://strongpasswordgenerator.com/ 2) copypaste to change your login password 3) copypaste to email this password to yourself in the future https://www.futureme.org/ 4) log out, clear your clipboard.

Comment: I would give that a hard +1 in the answer box, @will.

Answer (score 30):

*In theory*, [this has been done before](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/conversation/i-need-a-mod-to-suspend-me), but I believe there are more, umm, sane ways to achieve what you want. So, yes, you can get your account suspended, but I don't recommend doing this a custom.

Comment: Just because it's happened once doesn't mean it will happen again. If someone requested this today, they'd get a firm no.

Comment: @animuson In theory, there is no difference between theory and practice. But, in practice, there is.